# Безопасность кода на клиенте

Tags: клиент, клиент-сервер, javascript

Не много работаю с вебом и первый раз основательно с клиентской частью, ExtJs если быть точным (web-desktop). Делаем "навороченную" админку. Я реализую авторизацию. Например, есть роли пользователей Admin, User и др. Получаю данные о пользователе и сохраняю в массиве. Потом делаю проверку if(this.user_info['role']=='Admin')... Все логично. Вопрос: не сможет ли пользователь на клиенте просто поменять содержимое JS-файла. Например, на if(this.user_info['role']=='User') для выполнения ему не предназначающегося кода? И вообще, нормальноли, что на клиенте весь JS-код? Включая админский и др. Просто приложение полностью на аяксе (ExtJS ведь) и возможности какие-то админские js-файлы не подключать нет. Загружается все приложение и после авторизации все решается на клиенте, получая аяксом с сервера необходимые данные. Безопасно ли это? Конечно, на сервере любое админское действие я буду проверять тем, кто авторизован в данный момент. Но вопрос все же "для себя на будущее")

Comment: Собственно я так понял, всё упирается в то, что если "юзер подменит запрос". Конечно нужно все данные проверять на сервере. Если вдруг права не совпадают, то сервер должен отдать определенный ответ, а клиент его обработать (например javascript'ом вывести ошибку).

Comment: @lampa, ну хотелось бы еще услышать методы защиты. Вот сейчас случайно наткнулся на обфускаторы js-кода. Обязательно воспользуюсь пожалуй.

Comment: @Андрей Бакша какие методы защиты? обфускатор не поможет, запрос посмотреть можно и через обладчик. Не беспокойтесь на счет клиентского кода (js), все данные всё равно вы должны проверять на сервере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое и самое главное правило – все, что приходит от пользователя или каким-либо образом может быть им изменено, должно проходить обязательную проверку на стороне сервера. Ну, и разумеется, не отправлять ему тех данных, которые не должны ему быть отправлены.

Всё остальное - вторично, т.к. и обфусцированный код декомпилируется.